# Lighttpd redirect passing original URL

Tags: lighttpd

I would like to redirect `http://foo/bar to http://bar/foo?q=http://foo/bar`

Where foo and bar are dynamic...

But I cant seem to find a $HTTP var that has the complete url.
I have also tried nesting, but I can't get a reference to Scheme (its overwritten by host)

How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are only two schemes you can simply duplicate that config part for each possible scheme.

Comment: what would that look like? I currently use  $HTTP["host"] in order to get the incoming domain. If I nest  $HTTP["scheme"] and  $HTTP["host"] I lose one of them (i.e. %0 only refers to the inner most)

Comment: Doh! I dont need to reference scheme, just match it! Got it.